# Embedding a list in org-mode tables?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Can I have tables like the following generated using org-mode,

```
Day 1 | a) A |
      | b) B |
      | c) C |
Day 2 | a) D |
Day 3 | a) E |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
|-----------+------|
| Monday    | a) A |
|           | b) B |
|           | c) C |
|-----------+------|
| Tuesday   | a) D |
|-----------+------|
| Wednesday | a) E |
|-----------+------|
```

I just entered

```
|||
```

Then <kbd>RET</kbd> inside the table to get more rows and <kbd>C-RET</kbd> to get lines. Fill out and go. Seems to export to HTML and text just fine...

Answer (score 1):

Also you can write a function that converts arbitrary elisp list of lists  to table. It can be useful to debug (message the "table" string to *Messages* buffer) lists of lists.
Something like this:

```
(defun list-of-lists-to-org-table (lol &optional justify min-cell-width columns)
  (let ((buf (get-buffer-create "*org-tb*")))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (erase-buffer)
      (mapcar (lambda (x)
                (mapcar (lambda (y) (insert (format "%s&" y))) x)(insert "\n")) lol)
      (table-capture 1 (point-max) "&" "\n" justify min-cell-width columns)
      (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))
      )))
```

Example input:
`(list-of-lists-to-org-table '((Abc Def "xyz") (1 1 X1) (2 4 X2) (3 9 X3) (4 16 X4)))`

Example output:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|Abc  |Def  |xyz  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|1    |1    |X1   |
+-----+-----+-----+
|2    |4    |X2   |
+-----+-----+-----+
|3    |9    |X3   |
+-----+-----+-----+
|4    |16   |X4   |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

@Рустам Усманов
Your answer was very useful for me. However, in my case the function you provided inserts additional column and a row to the output table, so here's a slightly modified version of your code (note deletion last `&` in each row):

```
(defun list-of-lists-to-org-table (lol &optional justify min-cell-width columns)
(let ((buf (get-buffer-create "*org-tb*")))
 (with-current-buffer buf
  (erase-buffer)
  (mapcar (lambda (x)
    (mapcar (lambda (y)
          (insert (format "%s&" y)) ) x)
    (delete-char -1)
      )
      lol)
  (table-capture 1 (point-max) "&" "\n" justify min-cell-width columns)
  (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))
  )))
```